# Get values using regex in Python

Tags: python, regex, regex-group

How can I get the values 4 and 5 for test1 using only regex. I have this string:

```
  test1 =                 -2,                 2,                 2,                 0,                 0,                 0,                 0,                 0,                 0,                 0
  test2=              27000,             20000,             30000,             16200,              8000,              8000,              8000,              8000,              8000,              8000
  test3 =               1500,              1500,              1500,              1500,              1500,              1500,              1500,              1500,              1500,              1500
  test4 =               7000,              7000,              7000,              8000,              8000,              4000,              4000,              4000,              4000,              4000
  test5 =                500
```

I have this command:

```
`\s(test)\s*=(?P<test>\D.*)`
```

It selects 2 groups, but I would like to have the values 4 and 5. Or is there any other way? I don't want to use pandas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import re

regex = r"test1\s*=\s*-?\d+,\s*-?\d+,\s*-?\d+,\s*(-?\d+),\s*(-?\d+)"

test_str = YOUR_STR

matches = re.finditer(regex, test_str, re.MULTILINE)

for matchNum, match in enumerate(matches):
    matchNum = matchNum + 1

    print ("Match {matchNum} was found at {start}-{end}: {match}".format(matchNum = matchNum, start = match.start(), end = match.end(), match = match.group()))

    for groupNum in range(0, len(match.groups())):
        groupNum = groupNum + 1

        print ("Group {groupNum} found at {start}-{end}: {group}".format(groupNum = groupNum, start = match.start(groupNum), end = match.end(groupNum), group = match.group(groupNum)))
```

regex101.com is a useful tool if you're trying out regex. The site also generates the code for you.

I got the above code from there. https://regex101.com/r/WMUbLf/1

Answer (score 0):

```
s="""test1 =                 -2,                 2,                 2,                 0,                 0,                 0,                 0,                 0,                 0,                 0
  test2=              27000,             20000,             30000,             16200,              8000,              8000,              8000,              8000,              8000,              8000
  test3 =               1500,              1500,              1500,              1500,              1500,              1500,              1500,              1500,              1500,              1500
  test4 =               7000,              7000,              7000,              8000,              8000,              4000,              4000,              4000,              4000,              4000
  test5 =                500"""

import re

lines = s.splitlines()
g1 = re.findall('[-0-9]+', lines[3])[1:] # test4
g2 = re.findall('[-0-9]+', lines[4])[1:] # test5
print(g1)
print(g2)
```

Output:

```
['7000', '7000', '7000', '8000', '8000', '4000', '4000', '4000', '4000', '4000']
['500']
```

Comment: HI @Andrej, thanks for the reply. I already tried this. the problem is i have more than 10k files. If i use findall function. It would take some time to compile.

Comment: @PUser I don't understand, you have lot's of short strings? You can compile regexp once and use compiled version afterwards.

Comment: I just updated the file. I only need test1 with 4 and 5 values. SOrry if it was confusing